# Calculating Polygonal Numbers Taking A While To Calculate

Tags: python

I've created a function which, hopefully, creates a list of numbers that are both pentagonal and square.

Here is what i've got so far:

```
def sqpent(n):
    i = 0
    list = []
    while n >= 0:
        if n == 0:
            list.append(0)
        elif n == 1:
            list.append(1)
        elif (i*i == (i*(3*i-1)//2)):
            list.append(i)
            n -= 1
        i += 1
```

But when it gets past the first two numbers it seems to be taking a while to do so...

Comment: when n = 1 or n= 0 you go into an infinite loop. Put  'n -= 1' at the same level as 'i += 1'

Comment: The only numbers for which `i*i == (i*(3*i-1)//2)` are 0 and 1. Your problem is assuming that it will be the same value of `i` for the square and pentagonal number, which is not true.

Comment: As you progress, throw some `print` statements in there so you can watch it in action.

Comment: Ahh i see the issue @interjay.. So would i have to use two for loops in a range of n?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma That can work, but will be very slow. See my answer for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @interjay's advice, I came up with this answer which works perfectly:

```
import math

def sqpent(n):
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    l = []
    while counter < n:
        x = (i*(3*i-1)//2)
        #print(x)
        if(int(math.sqrt(x))**2 == x):
            #print("APPENDED: " + str(x))
            l.append(x)
            counter += 1
        i += 1
    return l
```

For an explanation:

- It iterates through a value i, and gets the ith pentagonal number. Then it checks if it is a square and if so it appends it to a list which i ultimately return.
- It does this until a final point when the counter reaches the number of items in the list you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues: the first is that the special-casing for `n==0` and `n==1` doesn't decrease `n`, so it goes into an infinite loop. The special-casing isn't really needed and can be dropped.

The second, and more significant one, is that in the test `i*i == (i*(3*i-1)//2)` you are assuming that the index `i` will be the same for the square and pentagonal number. But this will only happen for `i==0` and `i==1`, so you won't find values past that.

I suggest:

1. Iterate over `i` instead of `n` to make things simpler.
2. Take the `i`th pentagonal number and check if it is a square number (e.g. `int(sqrt(x))**2 == x`).
3. Stop when you've reached `n` numbers.

Comment: Posted an answer based on your suggestions! Thank you :)